# Passing tokenized strings to Google Translate API

Tags: parsing, tokenize, google-translation-api

I've written a program which translates strings by passing them to **Google's Cloud Translate API**. The majority of these strings are simple, as in:

> I am a string! Please translate me!

But some of them are **tokenized**, as in:

> Page {1} of {2}

What is the correct way to pass these tokenized strings to the API? If I pass in the tokenized strings as they are, bugs start to creep in. For example, if I pass in `Page {1} of {2}` and ask Google to translate it into Italian, it returns:

> Pagina 1 di 2}

**Is there a recommended method for passing such tokenized strings to Google's API?** If there is such a method, would it stop bugs such as the above from cropping up?

---

Note: I am aware of the following workaround: `Page <span>{1}</span> of <span>{2}</span>`. However since the strings I'm working with sometimes include snippets of HTML, that doesn't look like a viable long-term strategy.

Comment: Did you maybe mean **templated** instead of **tokenized**? Or is this some domain-specific meaning of "tokenize" which I've never before stumbled over?

Comment: Can you share a complete sample code? Just so the community members can easily reproduce the problem. Also to clarify, are you trying to prevent Translate API to translate {1} and {2}?

Comment: @rici The term "token" is used for something that looks like `{0}` in the codebase I'm currently working with. I was confused by it too!

Comment: @RiccoD Unfortunately, the company I'm working for is a bit paranoid about their codebase, and my head would be on a spike before the end of the day if I posted any code here. What I *can* tell you is that an API call is made to Google Cloud Services, the string `Page {1} of {2}` is passed in, and `Pagina 1 di 2}` is returned. You can replicate the issue exactly if you try to translate `Page {1} of {2}` into, say, Italian, using https://translate.google.co.uk.